# UICollectionView: inconsistent expanding cell animations

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uikit

After a frustrating amount of time in trying to "fix" my inconsistent expanding collection cell animations, I have determined that UICollectionView / FlowLayout uses different animations depending on the ratio of cell expansion, with the threshold of 2:1.

If the ratio is under 2:1, you get this:

[image]

If the ratio is equal to or greater than 2:1, you get this:

[image]

Does anyone know if this can be configured?

The offending code (with some syntactic sugar) is:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let cell = SimpleCalculatedSizeCell.prototype
    let contents = data[indexPath.item]
    cell.label.text = contents
    let width = collectionView.bounds
        .inset(collectionView.contentInset)
        .inset(layout.sectionInset)
        .width
    let finalSize = cell.systemLayoutSizeFitting(
        .init(width: width, height: 0),
        withHorizontalFittingPriority: .required,
        verticalFittingPriority: .fittingSizeLevel)
        .withWidth(width)

    if let selected = selected, selected == indexPath {
        print("\(#function): \(finalSize)")
        return finalSize.withHeight(150)
    }

    print("\(#function): \(finalSize)")

    // return finalSize.withHeight(76) // expands smoothly
    return finalSize.withHeight(75)    // fades and snaps
}
```

with an the selection handling of:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selected = selected == indexPath ? nil : indexPath

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
        collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
        collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
```

Thanks!